# filling data in a 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a battleship game in c++. what i am doing is trying to make start and endpoints of the ship's locations and then the program will fill in the gap to complete the ship. the `int size` part is to tell the program which ship is there. eg. small, medium or large ship. for some reason i dont understand why this wont work

```
int fill(int arr[10][10], int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int size){

    if(x1 == x2){
        if(y1 > y2){
            for(int i = y2; i < y1; i++){arr[x1][i] = size;}
        }

        else{
            for(int i = y1; i <= y2; i++){arr[x1][i] = size;}
        }
    }
    else if(y1 == y2){
        if(x1 > x2){
            for(int i = x2; i < x1; i++){arr[y1][i] = size;}
        }
        else{for(int i = x1; i <= x2; i++){arr[y1][i] = size;}}
    }
    return arr;

}
```

when i pass the variables, `x1 = 4, y1 = 4, x2 = 6, y2 = 4, size = 3`, it wont fill in the gap and the space in between the start/end points are still empty.

my full code can be found here: https://repl.it/@SakshamGoyal/project
it is still a work in progress so there will be alot of redundant code

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Why are you ignoring warning messages from your compiler? No self-respecting C++ compiler will compile the shown code without at least a warning message, and I would say that no C++ compiler worth using is going to compile this successfully. Although the error here (`arr` cannot be returned as an `int`) doesn't seem germane to your problem, it's highly probable that it's also complaining about other things, which might be the reason for your problem. Do not ignore warning messages from your compiler. The compiler doesn't emit warning messages just to confuse you. It complains for a reason.

Comment: Please go and learn how to pass 2D array to function in C++

Comment: I'm seeing errors with the fact that you are passing a 2D array into the function and also returning that value. The compiler should be giving you warnings. Are you trying to return the array?

Comment: @garry i am using the online compiler repl.it which shows me no errors. which should i use?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  i am using the online compiler repl.it which shows me no errors. which should i use?

Comment: @SakshamGoyal I just attempted to run your function in repl.it and received compiler errors.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik refresh the page and try again. i just edited the code

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius which one should i use?

Comment: You should use `gcc`, which comes with every Linux distribution. If you are serious about learning C++, you should install Linux and use gcc to learn C++.

Comment: Don't use an online compiler. Get yourself a copy of Visual Studio Community edition or clang or GCC with a nice, friendly user interface frontend that makes debugging with GDB easier. The online tools just aren't  as nice to use. While you are learning why fight with the tools more than you absolutely have to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only to fill in the array, you can make the return type of the method `void`. Other than this, your code is alright:

```
void fill(int arr[10][10], int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int size) {
    if (x1 == x2) {
        if (y1 > y2) {
            for (int i = y2; i < y1; i++) {
                arr[x1][i] = size;
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = y1; i <= y2; i++) {
                arr[x1][i] = size;
            }
        }
    } else if (y1 == y2) {
        if (x1 > x2) {
            for (int i = x2; i < x1; i++) {
                arr[y1][i] = size;
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = x1; i <= x2; i++) {
                arr[y1][i] = size;
            }
        }
    }
}

void fillZero(int a[10][10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            a[i][j] = 0;
}

int main() {
    int a[10][10];
    fillZero(a);
    fill(a, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2);
    // Print array:
    for (auto &i : a) {
        for (int j : i)
            cout << j << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to run that but it doesnt fill it in. is it because i am passing an array and it isnt making the changes to the global variable of the array?

Comment: i litterally just changed the parameters from int arr[10][10] to int arr[][10] since c++ allows that by accident and for some strange reason, IT WORKED!!!!! change your answer and il mark as answer

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure why this is the case. I tried running my code in C++ 98, 11, 14 and 17. All versions run the code just fine. Following what you did to make it work for you, it also works for me. Perhaps we're using different compilers.